# htaccess htpasswd no prompt

Tags: .htaccess, authentication, prompt, .htpasswd

I'm trying to protect a folder using '.htaccess' and '.htpasswd'.

I used http://www.tools.dynamicdrive.com/password/ to generate the files.

Copied them to the corresponding folders.

When I attempted to access the protected folder, **I got a login prompt.**

Input incorrect login details, get sent to error page.

All good.

Now, without any changes, I revisit the page to try and login again to access the protected folder, and it just throws an error, **there's no login box.**

If I delete the .htaccess, I can get into the folder again without errors.

Upon replacing the .htacces, I get the error again, **still no login box.**

I have tried to regenerate a new set of files, user/pass combo, and slight modifications to .htaccess just to try get some form of response back.

I have checked for any bytemark, both files are clean UTF-8.

**What's going on? Why am I not getting a prompt anymore?**

On a side note, where should the log be? All I managed to find was some access logs with nothing useful in them.

---

Site location on server

```
/home/labvccom/
```

/home/labvccom/public_html/admin/.htaccess

```
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /htpasswords/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
require valid-user
```

/home/labvccom/htpasswords/.htpasswd [user: admin | pass: password]

```
admin:02yd6IWnPes66
```

---

This is the page that i get when it throws the error with NO login prompt

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@labvc.com.au and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Apache/2.2.17 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_fcgid/2.3.5 Phusion_Passenger/2.2.15 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 Server at labvc.com.au Port 80
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your browser remembers the first login attempt and send the credentials in the [Authorization](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.8) header - that is why you do not get a new login prompt.

Try to clear the authorization cache.

The underlying problem is most likely as @openscript.ch suggests.

Comment: Cleared ALL my browsing data from chrome, reloaded page, and again it jumps right to the error with no login box.

Comment: Do you have access to the servers error log? If not, you could try to set up an apache server on your own machine.

Comment: I probably do have access, but i don't know where to look.
I have XAMP running on my computer, which i use most of the time, and it throws up the same problem.
I get one login attempt, then permanent 500 errors.

Comment: I would guess something like `/opt/lampp/logs/error_log`, `/var/log/apache/error_log` or something simiar. Check `httpd.conf`, it should contain an `ErrorLog` row with details about where errors are logged.

Comment: Somehow, my .htacces file got a little bit of a typo in it.
It was linked to "/htpasswords/.htaccess"
instead of "/htpasswords/.htpasswd"
Thanks for the help!

Comment: I know your issue was solved differently, but for others who find this answer helpful to their issue, adding: for me, cf_bm cookie was still present for my web page/wouldn't delete via 'Clear site data' + all cookies. Had to delete that manually and next hard reload worked. Could not reproduce with the new cookie, so maybe something's up with some of the cookies cf issues. Anyway, if button doesn't work, try manual kill of all cookies.

Answer (score 1):

I think your path to the .htpasswd-File is wrong. If it is not absolute, it is treated as relative to the ServerRoot.
Try to use an absolute path to your .htpasswd-File.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create login/pass .htaccess inside the folder that you want to protect... otherwise the trick will not work as wanted! I created some days ago a simple php tool that creates login/pass for you. It's a part of another my project... so I extracted it from my archive for you. Pay attention that under windows the password is sent clear... is not a bug of my script but a request by windows servers. So use only it in remote hosting with unix, linux running apache. Put apache-ht.php inside the folder you want to protect and then execute it. Be prompted to create user/pass! After done delete apache-ht.php from folder. You fail because you are trying to set relative path. This kind of .htaccess needs full path! I hope this helps:

apache-ht.php

```
<?php
  ############################################
  # Created By Alessandro Marinuzzi [Alecos] #
  # apache-ht.php - Version 1.5 - 07/04/2015 #
  # WebSite: ---> http://www.alecos.it/ <--- #
  ############################################
  if ((isset($_POST['username']) && (!empty($_POST['username']))) && ((isset($_POST['password'])) && (!empty($_POST['password'])))) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Apache - Username :: Password Generator</title>
<style type="text/css">
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed);
html {
  display: table;
}
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background-color: lightgray;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-family: Oswald, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
}
.mainbox {
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: darkgray;
  width: 420px;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
}
.title {
  font-family: Oswald, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
.save {
  font-family: Oswald, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: darkviolet;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: inset -5px 5px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15), inset 5px -5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}
.data {
  font-family: Oswald, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
.doit {
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
.user {
  font-family: Oswald, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  background-color: #006699;
  border: #C0C0C0 2px solid;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: white;
  width: 80px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.pass {
  font-family: Oswald, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  background-color: #006699;
  border: #C0C0C0 2px solid;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: white;
  width: 80px;
  margin: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    if ((substr($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],-1,1) == "/") && (substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],0,1) =="/")) {
      $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . substr(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']),1) . "/.htpasswd";
    } else {
      $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . "/.htpasswd";
    }
    $tmp1 = fopen(".htaccess", "w");
    $tmp2 = "AuthType Basic\n";
    $tmp2 .= "AuthName \"Restricted Area\"\n";
    $tmp2 .= "AuthUserFile \"$path\"\n";
    $tmp2 .= "Require valid-user\n";
    fwrite($tmp1, $tmp2);
    fclose($tmp1);
    unset($tmp1);
    unset($tmp2);
    if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS,0,3) == 'WIN')) {
      $tmp1 = fopen(".htpasswd", "w");
      $tmp2 = "$username:$password\n";
      fwrite($tmp1, $tmp2);
      fclose($tmp1);
      unset($tmp1);
      unset($tmp2);
    } else {
      $tmp1 = fopen(".htpasswd", "w");
      $tmp2 = "$username:" . crypt($password,'$6$rounds=5000$usesomesillystringforsalt$') . "\n";
      fwrite($tmp1, $tmp2);
      fclose($tmp1);
      unset($tmp1);
      unset($tmp2);
    }
    exit("<div class=\"mainbox\">\n<span class=\"title\">Apache - Username :: Password Generated!</span>\n</div>\n</body>\n</html>");
  }
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Apache - Username :: Password Generator</title>
<style type="text/css">
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed);
html {
  display: table;
}
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background-color: lightgray;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-family: Oswald, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
}
.mainbox {
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: darkgray;
  width: 420px;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
}
.title {
  font-family: Oswald, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
.save {
  font-family: Oswald, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: darkviolet;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: inset -5px 5px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15), inset 5px -5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}
.data {
  font-family: Oswald, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
.doit {
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
.user {
  font-family: Oswald, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  background-color: #006699;
  border: #C0C0C0 2px solid;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: white;
  width: 80px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.pass {
  font-family: Oswald, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  background-color: #006699;
  border: #C0C0C0 2px solid;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: white;
  width: 80px;
  margin: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="mainbox">
<span class="title">Apache - Username :: Password Generator</span><br>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<span class="data"><label for="username">Username:</label> <input type="text" class="user" id="username" name="username"></span><br>
<span class="data"><label for="password">Password:</label> <input type="text" class="pass" id="password" name="password"></span><br>
<span class="doit"><input type="submit" class="save" value="Create Username &amp; Password"></span><br>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This question was answered 4 years ago.